# Unix: What happens if I enter ls -d [2-q]*

Tags: shell, wildcards

Would it just ignore the bit after the -d option since you cant arrange characters lexically between 2 and q?

Comment: Please share with us the results of your research.

Answer (score 3):

Yes characters can be arranged lexically between 2 and q. Do an `ls /bin` and you'll see the numerics come before the letters. In fact you can do `ls /bin/[2-q]*` and see for yourself exactly what happens.

Lexical sorting in the "C" locale is by ASCII value, so '2' is 32 decimal, and 'q' is 71. Do a `man ascii` to see the whole ASCII table.

Perhaps you meant to ask what happens if you *do* specify an illegal lexographic range? You could try:

> % ls /bin/[q-2]*
>   ls: cannot access /bin/[q-2]*: No such file or directory

Of course, your shell is expanding that pattern (aka "filename GLOB expansion"), so the error you see might depend on your shell and shell options. In my case I use `zsh` and have set `zsh` options to pass through patterns that cannot be GLOB expanded directly to the command being invoked, rather than generating a shell error which would abort the command execution.